# Move terms from one taxonomy to another keeping the hierarchy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, user-interface

I am creating a **custom taxonomy** for the first time. I am trying to add a `Location` taxonomy. What I am actually trying to do is use existing *categories* to make them into *locations*.

I went into the database table `wp_term_taxonomy` and manually changed the `taxonomy` column of the ones I wanted from `category` to `location`.
This seemed to work pretty well, posts are assigned to the desired locations and everything seems to be fine, until I go to the *Locations* page in the admin interface and find myself with an empty list, even though it detects the existing locations and lists them:

[screenshot http://zaharamh.com/locationwtf.gif](http://zaharamh.com/locationwtf.gif)

If I manually add a new *Location* through the interface it appears on the list correctly.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I checked this answer (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51284/how-to-convert-regular-categories-to-custom-taxonomy) but I actually want to keep the hierarchy so it does not work for me

Comment: Apparently this was due to a "countries" `Category` not being changed into a `Location`.

Now I know: if the parent term is missing, the child term will not be shown on the list.

(*I wonder if this whole question should be deleted or would it be of any use to other people?*)